# Consulta de uma data entre duas datas

Tags: php, mysql

Precisava consultar se uma determinada data esta contida em um intervalo de datas. Sendo mais especifico, em um sistema que temos de controle de veículos, ao recebermos uma multa, precisamos identificar o condutor que estava com um determinado veiculo no dia em questão.

Exemplo:

```
$data_saida (registrada quando o veiculo sai)
$data_retorno (registrada quando o veiculo retorna)

$data_infracao = (registrada quando chega a multa)
$placa_veiculo = (registrada quando chega a multa)
```

Qual método que uso para confirmar de acordo com o horário da infração, quem, estava com o carro pela data, já que temos vários condutores adastrado? O veículo foi fácil, pois a placa vem na multa e é um identificador único...

Segue o código q estou executando:

```
<?php
$data = date('Y-m-d');
$hora = date("H:i:s");

$placa = $_POST ['multas'];
$data_i = $_POST ['data_i'];
$hora_i = $_POST ['hora_i'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM trafego WHERE '$data_i' BETWEEN 'data_s' AND 'data_e' AND placa='$placa'";
$verifica = mysqli_query ($strcon,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_num_rows ($verifica);
    if ($row >=1) {
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica)){
    $id_trafego = $resultado ['id_trafego'];
    $condutor = $resultado ['condutor'];
    $data_s = $resultado ['data_s'];  
    $hora_s = $resultado ['hora_s'];
    $data_e = $resultado ['data_e'];
    $hora_e = $resultado ['hora_e'];

    echo "<hr/>";
    echo $id_trafego;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "CONDUTOR:&nbsp;&nbsp;",$condutor;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "DATA SAÍDA:&nbsp;&nbsp;",date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data_s)),"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","HORA DA SAÍDA:&nbsp;&nbsp;",$hora_s;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "DATA RETORNO:&nbsp;&nbsp;",date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data_e)),"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","HORA RETORNO:&nbsp;&nbsp;",$hora_e;
    echo "<hr/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";


}
    }else{
        echo "<p><h3>Não existe registro de veículos em tráfego na data da multa.<br/>";
        echo "Verifique a data digitada, e tente novamente</p></h2>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Desculpe-me, corrigindo o ultimo parágrafo (coloquei em letras maiuscula a correção): Qual método que uso para confirmar de acordo com A DATA da infração, quem, estava com o carro, já que temos vários condutores cadastrado? O veículo foi fácil, pois a placa vem na multa e é um identificador único...

Answer (score 0):

Queria agradecer a todos a ajuda.

Fiz uma alteração no código colocando a segunda condição `WHERE` no caso 'placa', antes do `BETWEEN` e funcionou corretamente. Vou colar o código alterado abaixo.

A variável `$data_i` (data da infração) vem logo a seguir, mas nesse caso agora após a 'placa'. anteriormente a condição 'placa' estava no final.

**CÓDIGO CORRIGIDO**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trafego WHERE placa='$placa'AND'$data_i' BETWEEN data_s AND data_e";
$verifica = mysqli_query ($strcon,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_num_rows ($verifica);
        if ($row >=1) {
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica)){
    $id_trafego = $resultado ['id_trafego'];
    $condutor = $resultado ['condutor'];
    $data_s = $resultado ['data_s'];  
    $hora_s = $resultado ['hora_s'];
    $data_e = $resultado ['data_e'];
    $hora_e = $resultado ['hora_e'];
}
```